# Function having return type of struct return nothing every second time its called

Tags: c++, c, arduino, embedded, esp32

I am writing a program to receive SSID and password via BlueTooth in an ESP32 (Arduino Framework). The function BTSerialRcvBuffer() waits for BlueTooth, when it receives a string it returns the base address and size of the string via a variable of type struct Buffer_return. The function returns the SSID but not the password. I don't know why? Do I have to allocate memory for  Var.rtn_addr or allocating memory for variable buff1 and buff2 enough?

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <BluetoothSerial.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#define btrcv_buffer_size 256

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

typedef struct
{
  char *rtn_addr;
  int buff_len;
} Buffer_return;


Buffer_return* BTSerialRcvBuffer() {

  static int i = 0;
  static char rcv_buffer[ btrcv_buffer_size ];
  static Buffer_return Var;

  memset(rcv_buffer,0, btrcv_buffer_size);

  while (!SerialBT.available());
  delayMicroseconds(500);

  while(SerialBT.available()) {
    rcv_buffer[i] = SerialBT.read();
    i++;
  }
  rcv_buffer[i-1] = '\0';
  rcv_buffer[i-2] = '\0';
  SerialBT.flush();

  Var.rtn_addr = rcv_buffer;  //<------------Do I have to allocate memory for Var.rtn_addr?
  Var.buff_len = i-1;

  return &Var;
} 

void WiFiConfig() {

  //WiFi.printDiag(Serial);

  Serial.println("Enter SSID");
  Buffer_return *buff1 = BTSerialRcvBuffer();
  char *ssid = (char*) malloc((buff1->buff_len) * sizeof(char));  
  strcpy(ssid,buff1->rtn_addr);
  Serial.println(ssid);  

  Serial.println("Enter Password");
  Buffer_return *buff2 = BTSerialRcvBuffer();
  char *pass = (char*) malloc((buff2->buff_len) * sizeof(char));  
  strcpy(pass,buff2->rtn_addr);
  Serial.println(pass); 
  //Serial.println(buff2->buff_len);  


  free(ssid)
  free(pass);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Establishing connection to WiFi..");
    Serial.printf("Connection status: %d\n", WiFi.status());
  }  
}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  //WiFi.disconnect(true);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32_INO"); //Bluetooth device name
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");

  WiFiConfig();

  Serial.println("Connected to network");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {

  }
```

**Output:**

```
Enter SSID
Airtel_5G             <----- prints fine!
Enter Password
                      <----- Problem!
Establishing connection to WiFi..
Connection status: 6
Establishing connection to WiFi..
Connection status: 6
Establishing connection to WiFi..
Connection status: 6
```

Comment: `while(SerialBT.available()) {
    rcv_buffer[i] = SerialBT.read();
    i++;
  }
  rcv_buffer[i-1] = '\0';
  rcv_buffer[i-2] = '\0';` code is a problem any time `i > btrcv_buffer_size` or `i<2`.

Comment: Yup - I do not see any secure mechanism to ensure that only complete protocols units, (which seem to be text lines terminated with \r\n), are loaded from the byte stream. I can not see how this can work reliably.

Comment: Rather then having a static buffer in `BTSerialRcvBuffer()` then copying from it in `WiFiConfig()`, it would be far safer and more idiomatic to pass the buffer `ssid` and `pass` along with the max length as arguments to `BTSerialRcvBuffer()`.  Both statics and dynamic memory allocation are probably bet avoided on this platform.

Comment: regarding: `SerialBT.flush();`   The flush()' operation is for output streams, not input streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code uses the the following sequence to copy input data to a buffer.

```
  Buffer_return *buff1 = BTSerialRcvBuffer();
  char *ssid = (char*) malloc((buff1->buff_len) * sizeof(char));  
  strcpy(ssid,buff1->rtn_addr);
```

Recall the strings are NUL terminated, so that allocation must include extra byte!. Simple update to malloc call:

```
char *ssid = (char*) malloc((buff1->buff_len+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Per input from @lundin, malloc is not recommedned for Arduino. Better to use automatic allocation.

See also: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/682/is-using-malloc-and-free-a-really-bad-idea-on-arduino

```
  char ssid[buff2->buff_len+1] ;
  strcpy(ssid, buff2->rtn_addr) ;
```

**Update 1: error in BTSerialRcvBuffer**

The `BTSerialRcvBuffer` uses static for many variables, including `i`. Recall that static variables are initialized once (at program startup). Suggesting removing 'static' from `i` - to fix the initialization, as there is no need to make it static.

Also, it is not clear why are the last 2 positions of `rcv_buffer` reset to zero ?

Comment: still the same problem exists. I tried allocating more memory but still the same.

Comment: I suggest that you will step through the code with a debugger - it will be faster. See note in code

Comment: At present no debugger for esp32 is available with me.

Comment: can you make sure everything inside BTSerialRcvBuffer() is fine?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand `make sure everything ... is fine`.

Comment: I want to remove \r and \n, that why I resets last positions to zero.

Comment: Everything is working fine when I remove static from variable i.

Comment: Thanks for updating. You might want to make the zeroing conditional on (i>=2) and having \r and \n in the input. Just in case. Good luck with rest of project!

Comment: will do! Thank you so much!

Comment: This is tagged Arduino. Telling them to use malloc is harmful advise. In addition, `strndup` isn't standard C so that's even worse advise.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for bring the Arduino tag. I've missed it. I'll revised. The original answer used `malloc`, so this is a good advice to the poster.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of bad practice and slow function calls in your code. Keep in mind that this is a 8 bit MCU, so it is dreadfully slow. Some things to fix:

- It isn't necessary to zero-out the rx buffer each time. Just keep track of how large a portion of it that contains valid data. The `memset` call on 256 bytes is very expensive.
- It is common practice to double-buffer rx buffers so that one buffer can be used for reception and another for decoding, simultaneously. You don't use interrupts so this is perhaps less of an issue. 256 bytes is a lot of RAM anyway, so double buffering might require a better MCU if you need to store that much data. I'll use a double buffer example below anyway just to show how it can be done.
- The `delayMicroseconds(500);` does nothing meaningful except hanging up your program for 500ms. Remove that.
- Bug: you don't check for buffer overrun during reception.

---

```
#define BT_RXBUF_SIZE 256

const char* BTSerialReceive (size_t* size_rec) 
{
  static char buf1 [BT_RXBUF_SIZE];
  static char buf2 [BT_RXBUF_SIZE];
  static char* buf = buf1;

  buf = (buf == buf1) ? buf2 : buf1; // swap rx buffers


  while (!SerialBT.available())
    ;


  size_t i=0;
  for(; SerialBT.available() && i<BT_RXBUF_SIZE; i++)
  {
    buf[i] = SerialBT.read();
  }
  buf[i] = '\0';

  SerialBT.flush();

  *size_rec = i;
  return buf;
}
```

The pointer swap with double buffers eliminates the need for `memcpy`/`strcpy` which are slow and expensive. If you used UART interrupts you would have to use a design like this, for re-entrancy reasons.

Another thing that you must absolutely avoid is `malloc`. It is slow and senseless, [see this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/171581/6102). When working with embedded systems you must always use fixed-length buffers and deterministic amounts of memory. Getting rid of `malloc` means you can get rid of the whole heap segment in the linker script, which will free up lots of valuable RAM.

Comment: I've got a nasty feeling that the,delay is an attempt at a protocol, a very bad way of trying to ensure that the buffer contains a complete message with \r\n at the end.  That would be as reliable as you would expect:((